# Measuring if sampling technique has statistically significant effect

Tags: statistical-significance, sampling, chi-squared-test

Suppose I have a population where some subjects have a property $P$ and some do not. Further, I have a sampling technique which I use to extract a sample of 10,000 subjects. Of those 10,000, 20 exhibit $P$ and the rest do not. If instead I extract a random (disjoint) sample of the same size, only 5 subject exhibit $P$. Now I want to know if the sampling technique used (mine or random) has a statistically significant effect on the number of subject in a sample that exhibit $P$ (to be clear, the numbers in this example are made up).

My first idea would be to use $\chi^2$ or Fisher, but I am not sure it is correct. Specifically, those test assume a random sample which here is violated by the very nature of the problem. I am on the right path or should I use a different test?

Comment: Neither test requires your samples to be random.  Their *null hypotheses,* which in most applications are counterfactual, assume for the sake of analysis that the sampling is random.  The tests tell you how consistent that assumption is with your data.  But in your example the difference is clear and incontrovertible, so why are you testing at all? Wouldn't you rather be interested in quantifying the effect of your sampling procedure?

Comment: Yeah, I am aware that with this sample size and imbalance, almost any difference will be statistically significant, which is my other concern with this approach. I would assume though that sample sizes can be computed from $\chi^2$ or Fisher in the usual way? Or are the odd ratios more commonly reported?